# How to plot pandas dataframe column with x-axis defined by two other columns giving start and end values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe **df** of the form:

```
startTime  endTime  valCol
1            5        6
5            10       7
10           15       9.25
```

I want to use matplotlib or seaborn to create a line plot where:

1. x-axis is the range between 1 to 15
2. y-axis is the *valCol*

Here, I want x-axis values to have corresponding y values based on the range they are in. Essentially, the x-y pairs would look like:

```
[(1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6), (5,7), (6,7), (7,7), (8,7), (9,7), (10,9.25),\
(11,9.25), (12,9.25), (13,9.25), (14,9.25)]
```

Here is what I've tried so far. It does not seem to work appropriately (does not give a line plot, for one) and is also very slow for a moderate-size df to run because of the ilocs.

```
fixedIntervalLength=5
for index,row in df.iterrows(): 
    plt.plot(range(row['startTime'].astype(int), 
    row['endTime'].astype(int)), [row['valCol']]*fixedIntervalLength)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have an attempt?

Comment: yes, I'll try to insert the code.

Comment: @ifly6 I've added my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that involves making a new DataFrame.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [i, row['valCol']]
    for idx, row in df.iterrows()
    for i in range(*row[['startTime', 'endTime']].astype(int))
], columns=['x', 'y'])
new_df.plot(x='x', y='y')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
# get min and max time
min_time, max_time = df['startTime'].min(), df['endTime'].max()

# set startTime as index
df.set_index('startTime', inplace=True)

# reindex to new time range
# if your start/end times are actual timestamp
# use pd.daterange(min_time, max_time, freq='your_freq')
df = df.reindex(np.arange(min_time, max_time))

# ffill values
df['valCol'] = df['valCol'].ffill()

# plot
df['valCol'].plot()
```

output:

[image]